# What does "LRIG" mean?

Tags: wixoss

We know that Tama is Ruko's "LRIG" card, but is it ever explained what an LRIG actually stands for or what it means?

[image: Tama]

I was looking at some translated card game rules also, and they never referred to these cards as anything other than LRIGs. Have I missed something early on, or have they neglected to explain the term?

Comment: This is just speculation and might be completely off-base, but I think they might have just taken "girl" and spelled it backwards. I looked for this a little while back and couldn't find anything that indicated that it's actually an acronym/initialism.

Comment: Oh, I never even thought about that. It seems plausible alright

Comment: @senshin looking into it a little more, this seems to be right. The LRIG cards 'reflect' or sometimes 'invert' the potential Eternal Girls, like how both Tama and Ruko love battling, or Akira/Piriluk's hyperactive/calm combination

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like my guess was right - "LRIG" is "girl" spelled backwards, not an acronym/initialism.

This was stated by [KawaseP](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=28846) (a.k.a. Kouhei Kawase, one of the producers for *selector infected WIXOSS*) in [an interview with Akiba-Souken](http://akiba-souken.com/article/anime/19970/?page=2) (Ctrl+F for `作品要素`).

> ──LRIGs are a distinctive part of the show, aren't they?
>
> The LRIG character designs were done by [[Kyuta] Sakai](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=75758), but it was Tomo Yamaguchi, who is in charge of the card game at Takara Tomy, who came up with the name "LRIG". We had a different name for them at first, but at one of the scriptwriting meetings, we decided that we wanted to go with something a bit more off-the-beaten-path, and so we decided on "GIRL" spelled backwards: "LRIG" (pronounced "loo-rig"). Up to that point, we had been making up all sorts of convoluted words, so when the simple word "LRIG" was proposed, everybody agreed.

---

Given the events of episode 8...

> I guess we can see why the producers decided that "LRIG" was a good choice. Girls turn into LRIGs when their wishes are "fulfilled", and LRIGs likewise turn into (human) girls when that happens. Simple and effective.